# Bootstrap 3.3.7 How to close the navigation bar by clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I have a Drupal 8.6.8 site with Bootstrap 3.3.7 theme

I want my navigation menu to close when I click outside. I tried with the code :

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#navbar-collapse-first').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

}(jQuery));
```

https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

It does not work, if I click outside the navigation menu, it does not close. I want the menu to close only if I click outside. Even menu links should not close the menu unless the page is being reloaded.

Here is the code of the button of the navigation menu :

```
<div id="block-togglenavigationfirst" class="contextual-region">

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle-first collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-first" aria-expanded="false">

  <div class="icon-navbar-first">
    <span class="fa-layers fa-3x">
      <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
      <span class="navbar-icon-open">
        <i class="fas fa-th-list" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="navbar-icon-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-navbar-first-alert icon-navbar-first-alert-disable">
    <span class="fa-layers fa-3x">
      <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
      <span class="navbar-icon-open">
        <i class="fas fa-th-list fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="navbar-icon-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

</button>

</div>
```

Here is the navigation menu :

```
<div id="navbar-collapse-first" class="navbar-collapse-first width navbar-collapse-first-fixed-top collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
  <div class="region region-navigation-collapsible-first">
    <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-useraccountmenu-menu" id="block-useraccountmenu" class="contextual-region">
      <h2 class="sr-only" id="block-useraccountmenu-menu">User account menu</h2>          
      <ul class="menu menu--account nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="first last">
          <a href="/fr/unmasquerade" title="Retourner sur votre compte utilisateur.">Cesser de se faire passer pour quelqu'un d'autre</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check where did the click happen. If the click is outside the navbar then toggle it, otherwise don't do it.

Your javascript code would become:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

   $(document).click(function (event) {
       if (!($(event.target).is('#navbar-collapse-first *'))
           $('.navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
   });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I just applied your code, but when I click outside, it does not close.

Comment: I just visited your site and it seems to be working fine. On click inside the sidebar it doesn't hide it, and when I click on the blacked out area it closes the sidebar. Can you explain a case when it is not working specifically on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this solution from w3schools

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_close

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is about Modal. In my question, it's Collapse